# Can't draw things with EBOs

Tags: c++, opengl

In a C++ application I am writing I am trying to draw a quad using an EBO (element buffer object). Whenever I try to I can't get that quad to draw at all. What am  I doing wrong?
code:

```
//vertices and indices
GLfloat vertices[]={
//position              texture coordinate
-0.005f,0.02f,0.0f,      0.0f,1.0f,
0.02f,0.02f,0.0f,        1.0f,1.0f,
0.02f,-0.02f,0.0f,       1.0f,0.0f,
-0.005f,-0.02f,0.0f,     0.0f,0.0f,
};

GLfloat indices[]={
0,1,3,
2,3,1
};
//initialization
glCreateVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glCreateBuffers(1,&VBO);
glCreateBuffers(1,&EBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(indices),indices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,5*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,5*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindVertexArray(0);

//drawing commands
transformLocation=glGetUniformLocation(textureProgram,"transform");
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,woodTexture);
glUseProgram(textureProgram);
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(transform));
glBindVertexArray(bowHandleVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,bowHandleEBO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,nullptr);
```

This works with the glDrawArrays equivalent to this, but whenever I try to Use EBOs it won't draw anything. Comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most immediate error that I can see is a type mismatch between your indices definitions and usage at calling `glDrawElements`

**Suggestion:** Change GLFloat to GLuint, i.e., define your indices as:

```
GLuint indices[]={ //...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Amadeus says about changing your indices array from float to GLuint, you seem to be using the wrong VAO and EBO. In the code you show us you buffer all your data into a buffer object in `VAO` and indices to `EBO`, but then when you try to draw you're drawing with `bowHandleVAO` and `bowHandleEBO`.